# Commenting on a low quality post that doesn't warrant further action

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

When I'm reviewing low quality posts, I frequently come across posts ([eg](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts#low-quality-posts/4646757?&_suid=139833454881606742343462522395), [eg2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts#low-quality-posts/4646756?&_suid=13983342131040716296942718919)) that (I think) require a comment on how they could be improved, but not necessarily worth a downvote or a close vote, and I'm not in a position to edit it to improve it.

I'm hesitant to press <kbd>Looks good</kbd> in this situation as it doesn't at that time, leaving <kbd>Skip</kbd> as the only option, but then this doesn't count towards review totals, isn't recorded, or removed from the queue.

Is it acceptable to press <kbd>Looks good</kbd> in this situation?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180029#180029

Comment: related: [Rename “Looks Good” or add a “Looks OK, just Incorrect” in Low Quality Question Review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143015/rename-looks-good-or-add-a-looks-ok-just-incorrect-in-low-quality-question)

Comment: +1 this problem.  I just started reviewing these today and came across the same question.  After leaving a comment to improve (normally code only answers), I end up just hitting `SKIP` which doesn't remove it from the queue.  There needs to be a holding place for these where we leave comments, but they have not edited.  If no edits come, the post is low quality.

Comment: I tend to follow the advice "if it _attempts_ to answer the question, no matter how wrong it is, it's ok, otherwise, delete it. However, I feel the VLQ flag reason and queue are the most vague in the system.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, looks good means the question doesn't need any modification or extra review, which might lead to invalid statistics by the people running StackOverflow community to enhance it.

Pressing skip seems pretty much reasonable, even if it won't add to your review score, and it is not a competition, the review is there to help a community website that we all use to be in better shape.

last words, hit skip is always good, but it would be a great feature if SO suggests reviews based on your best scored tags, which are your strength fields.

Comment: users [can filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220922/new-bronze-badge-for-using-a-filter-on-the-close-votes-review-queue "it's just not well known") by tags in review queues, just like at [this screen shot taken from CV queue](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0pyUG.png)